# VBA in Word to avoid code if Tag does not exist

Tags: vba, ms-word, tags

I have an extensive code that populates tags using commands similar to the following :

```
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Tag1").Item(1).Range.Text = "New Item"
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Tag1").Item(2).Range.Text = "New Item"
```

However, if the user of the document deletes any of those tags 1 or 2 from the word document then the code will detect the tag does not exist, show an error and stop running the code. Hence my question...

1. Is it possible to count the number of Tags with a specific name, then IF that count returns 0 the code skips looking? I think I will be able to solve this issue if I can count per tag name, but yet to figure this out!

Comment: `If ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Tag1").Count <> 0 Then`? This condition will not work well for your example though as it could return `1` and pass the check but it will fail on this line `ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Tag1").Item(2).Range.Text = "New Item"`. since there's only 1 item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking up the documentation for [`SelectContentControlsByTitle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.selectcontentcontrolsbytitle) should have pushed you towards an answer.

> Returns a ContentControls collection that represents all the content
> controls in a document with the title specified in the Title
> parameter. Read-only.

As a collection has a `Count` property you can use that to determine how many items are in the collection, or you can loop through the members of the collection rather than writing to them individually.

The following will work without raising an error if there are no controls with that title:

```
Dim cc As ContentControl

For Each cc In ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Tag1")
    cc.Range.Text = "New Item"
Next cc
```